# What are the differences between iputils-ping and inetutils-ping?

Tags: debian, ping

I'm using a Debian 9 image on a virtual machine. The ping command is not installed. When I run:

```
sudo apt-get install ping
```

It asks me:

```
Package ping is a virtual package provided by:
  iputils-ping 3:20161105-1
  inetutils-ping 2:1.9.4-2+b1
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

Why is there two ping utilities? What are the differences between them? Is there some guidelines to choose one version over the other? What are the implications of this choice? Will all scripts and programs be compatible with both versions?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[`iputils`’s `ping`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iputils-ping/ping.8.en.html) supports quite a few more features than [`inetutils`’ `ping`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/inetutils-ping/ping.1.en.html), *e.g.* IPv6 (which `inetutils` implements in a separate binary, `ping6`), broadcast pings, quality of service bits... The linked manpages provide details.

`iputils`’ `ping` supports all the options available on `inetutils`’ `ping`, so scripts written for the latter will work fine with the former. The reverse is not true: scripts using `iputils`-specific options won’t work with `inetutils`.

As far as why both exist, `inetutils` is the [GNU networking utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/), targeting a variety of operating systems and providing lots of different networking tools; [`iputils`](https://github.com/iputils/iputils) is Linux-specific and includes fewer utilities. So typically you’d combine both to obtain complete coverage and support for Linux-specific features, on Linux, and only use `inetutils` on non-Linux systems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You say that typically you combine both to obtain complete coverage but as both implement the virtual package ping, If I install one the other is removed. How do you combine them?

Comment: @Ortomala I meant that you combine both sets of utilities: for example, `ftp` from `inetutils`, `ping` from `iputils`, etc. (That part of my answer wasn’t focused on `ping` specifically.)

Answer (score 15):

[`inetutils-ping`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/inetutils-ping) is the portable GNU implementation, which is used on non-Linux Debian systems (such as [*Debian GNU/kFreeBSD*](https://wiki.debian.org/Debian_GNU/kFreeBSD)).

[`iputils-ping`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/iputils-ping) is Linux only, but does have more features. If you are using Linux, you probably want `iputils` version of ping.

Comment: I learned from @StephenKitt's answer that `iputils-ping` supports ipv6 with same binary (`ipv6` is a symlink), while `inetutils-ping` provides a separate `ping6` binary. Both support *ipv6*, but the symbolic links aren't visible from packages.debian.org file listings.

Comment: i have tested the `ping` from both packages . `ping6` seems to work only when installing the `inetutils-ping` thx again

Comment: @GAD3R What do you need the `ping6` command for, if `ping` from `iputils-ping` supports both protocols? You can force it to use only either protocol with the `-4` and `-6` switches, should the need arise.

Comment: @GAD3R that’s weird, `iputils-ping` installs a `ping6` symlink, so you should be able to `ping6 ::` without installing `inetutils-ping` at all (and I can, on the systems I’ve checked this on).

Answer (score 3):

`iputils-ping` performs DNS reverse lookup via PTR query. You will have to wait for a timeout if there is no response from your DNS server.

`inetutils-ping` performs way more better in this situation.

Comment: Both implementations by default try to resolve IP addresses into names using reverse DNS lookups and require the `-n`  option to disable this behavior. Would you explain, how exactly `inetutils-ping` performs better?

Comment: @SebastianSchrader For `iputils-ping`, `-n` sets `opt_numeric`, which determines whether `pr_addr` will call `getnameinfo` without `NI_NUMERICHOST`, where a PTR query may happen. For `inetutils-ping`, it always calls `inet_ntoa` to convert sockaddr to string, a PTR resolution never happens. The interpretation of the `-n` flag and implementation of name resolution is rather complex behind the scene. It depends on what option you are using, what kind of response you are receiving, and even more. In general, `iputils-ping` may stuck when your DNS resolver doesn't respond to a PTR query in time.

Comment: Thanks for the details. `getnameinfo` with `NI_NUMERICHOST` (on glibc at least) is basically just a wrapper for `inet_ntop` (for IPv6 link-local addresses, it also tries to resolve the `scope_id` to an interface name using `if_indextoname`). With `-n` `iputils-ping` should therefore perform well too.

Comment: I'm iputils maintainer, I wonder if we should really stop doing DNS reverse lookup via PTR query by default (it can be avoided with `-n`, as mentioned). That would be a backward incompatibility change.

Comment: @pevik, I would welcome such a change. Per my past experience, I only need PTR lookup for mailing/mtr/mDNS. When I ping a target, I really don't care about what it says in its PTR record.

Comment: @youfu Thanks for info. I guess, since we have now option `-H` to force reverse DNS resolution, we could disable it by default (and suggest in man to either set alias + we could also introduce some variable, which would restore the old behavior without having to use `-H`). I'll post link with issue/PR here.

Comment: @youfu FYI https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/531 ([RFC] Disable reverse DNS resolution (PTR lookup)). Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can install one of them , the tow package provide the ping binary , the `inetutils-ping` will provide an additional tool `ping6`