# What's the difference between the telnetd and inetutils-telnetd packages in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, telnet, inetd

1. Recently, a work came to me which needs to set telnet on linemode.so i install telnetd with `apt install telnetd`, which is controlled by `inetd`, and this operation will add new line `telnet stream tcp nowait telnetd /usr/sbin/tcpd /usr/sbin/in.telnetd` in `/etc/inetd.conf`
2. after install telnetd by this way, i tried many ways to enable linemode in telnet service yet all failed ,so i removed telnetd by `apt remove telnetd`
3. then i reinstall `telnetd` by `apt install inetutils-telnetd`, this operation also add new line in `/etc/inetd.conf` which is `telnet stream tcp nowait telnetd /usr/sbin/tcpd /usr/sbin/telnetd`.after doing this, i add a `-l` option in this line and restart `telnetd`. in this way, line mode is enabled and works well.
4. althrough work is finished, but still can't i figure out why these two ways are different. what's the difference between these packages `telnetd` and `inetutils-telnetd`

Answer (score 3):

`telnetd` provides [the netkit implementation of `telnetd`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/netkit-telnet), whereas `inetutils-telnetd` provides [the GNU Inetutils implementation](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/). The latter [supports the `-l` option](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/inetutils-telnetd/telnetd.8.en.html#OPTIONS) to force line mode, whereas the former [relies on negotiation with the client](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/telnetd/in.telnetd.8.en.html#DESCRIPTION).

In most (if not all) cases, the Inetutils version of `telnetd` is more appropriate than the netkit version (within the limitations of the protocol).

See also [What are the differences between iputils-ping and inetutils-ping?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400351/86440)

Comment: thanks for replying, i get it. it's a treasure  for me to know why it behaves like this.

Comment: is there any way to enable line mode through telnetd?

Comment: What client are you using to connect to `telnetd`?

Comment: telnet client from windows features on win10